# Magento2 : The records are not getting saved in Database

Tags: magento2, database

I have a crazy issue that my record in the database is not getting saved.

- I've made a custom module. Which has model - And i am using it in a observer event before saving the shipment from admin panel

**OrderParams.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use Magento\Cron\Exception;
use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;


class RequestParams extends AbstractModel
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime
     */
    protected $_dateTime;

    /**
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(\Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\OrderParams::class);
    }
}
```

---

**ResourceMode/OrderParams.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb;


class OrderParams extends AbstractDb
{
    /**
     * Initialize resource
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('orders_params', 'id');
    }


}
```

- So if I use model for saving a record

  $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
  $reqParams=$objectManager->create('Vendor\Module\Model\OrderParams');

  ```
        try {
            /*$reqParams->setData([
                'order_id' => 1,
                'company_id' => 1
            ]);*/
            $reqParams->setOrderId(1);
            $reqParams->setCompanyId(1);
            $reqParams->save();
        }
        catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e)
        {
           $aa=$e->getMessage();
        }
  ```

So if you see above I have tried both ways.
And I have tried this with or without object manager as well. Still no luck. It doesn't even say that anything went wrong. It returns the result as TRUE.

SO I decided to do it with a direct SQL query

```
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
        $connection = $resource->getConnection();

        $insertData[] = ['order_id' => 14, 'company_id' => 1];
        $insertData[] = ['order_id' => 14, 'company_id' => 2];

        try {
            $connection->beginTransaction();
            $connection->insertMultiple('orders_params', $insertData);
            $connection->commit();
        } catch(\Exception $e) {
            $connection->rollBack();
        }
```

And i did it with insertMultiple() and direct SQL string query and insertArray()..
All went failed and all have a common issue that they say that it's successfully done But when I go to the DB table it's empty.

The surprising thing is when I copy the generated query from $VARIABLE using XDEBUGGER and run it directly in the SQL server. It successfully gets inserted.

One more surprising thing is if I fail any integrity constraint in my query. It says that the query has an issue and MySQL will not insert it.

Then I tried this in my other class which is basically a CARRIER model. And there it worked without having any change in the code. Just by copying and pasting it there.

But in my model, it's doing nothing.

Then I noticed in the database that if I put a record manually its has a different auto-increment id. So basically what I found out every time I try to insert a record. It gets inserts in the table. But somehow it gets deleted automatically.

For the confirmation, I turned on QUERY LOGGER in PHPMyAdmin and I found out my query there for inserting. But I did not find any delete query. But still, it's getting vanished after inserting somehow.

So can anyone help me out solving this issue?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I had already tried cache flushing. Even I ran all the setup upgrade, di complile and static content deploy in case. But still no luck

Answer (score 1):

I think Magento cache issue that's reason value not updated in Database table so please try to flush and clean Magento cache and then check.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had already tried cache flushing. Even I ran all the setup upgrade, di complile and static content deploy in case. But still no luck